# mixing video in bge

Tags: game-engine, video

I have a set of rendered sequences I'd like to mix live in BGE with the same result you would obtain using the cross effect in VSE.

BGE has already the capability to assign custom video texture to materials and I'm aware of [Dynamic texture](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341884) that's shows how to use the API but so far I can't imagine a good way to transition between a video and another. Maybe it's possible with using some way to overlay two planes but I'm lost on what's the best way to tackle this problem

I need to be able to control when this cross fading effect happens because all this will be screened LIVE in a theater and depending on the timing of the actors/orchestra a video sequence may loop or transition to the next video this are the only control I need.

I don't know if this is even possible with the BGE so if you have suggestion for other way to accomplish this they are welcome.

([FreeJ](https://www.dyne.org/software/freej/) seems unmaintained and [snowmix](http://snowmix.sourceforge.net/) seems to complicated for my needs)
([this branch](https://developer.blender.org/D1618) are for live cameras and won't help afaik)

edit: I just found that playing with z-transparency and two stacked planes makes a similar enough effect but how can I control it inside a BGE script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [praxis](http://www.praxislive.org) that offers a lot of transitions already built-in and endless possibilities since it integrate Processing

Answer (score 1):

Textures by VideoTextures are used within materials. There is no difference except the texture source is different. That means you can use it like any other material unless it overrides the settings you want to animate.

I suggest to animate the alpha component of the object color according to [Fading and Transparency for all Shading modes](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261926)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you need to know in advance where to place the keyframes to fade out

Comment: You do not need to know until it should start. You can play the transition action at any moment you like. It is independent from the texture.